# What different cannons exist in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends told me that their were several types of cannons in Minecraft, and that some where more powerful than others.

Is this true? If so, what is the best one?

Comment: There are no 'cannons' (if that is what you meant) in vanilla MC.

Comment: but i soe u can make some out of stone and tnt

Comment: kind of a tnt launcher then

Comment: [360 cannon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S3QH6hRRgg)

Comment: @ray — Then your question can't really be answered. There are almost as many different cannon designs as there are people making them. It's like asking how many types of house exist. :-)

Comment: I was JUST THINKING of asking a question like this...I was hoping there was some cannon "theory" out there, or accepted designs, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a single type of cannon; you drop lit TNT into water, and when it goes off it 'fires' the 'shell' that is at the edge of the water. TNT in water does not cause destruction; only the force of the blast is transmitted. Blocks are not destroyed, and damage is not applied.

Within this basic outline there is a vast variety in how the cannon can be constructed. This is likely what your friend is referring to. You can activate dozens of TNT at once as the 'charge', you can launch a variety of objects, animals, more TNT, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the strength of cannons is how many TNT shells they shoot. A cannon which shoots two shells (which is really two cannons) will be twice as damaging as one that shoots a single TNT.

The only other differences in cannons are range and ammo (as some require more TNT as propulsion).